# iOS 4.2 - dismissModalViewControllerAnimated method recalling ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, viewdidload

I am working with camera in my application. Here are steps how I am working.

1) In MyViewController, I am opening an ActionSheet.
2) On tap a button in that Action sheet opening camera using following code

```
 UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.allowsEditing = YES;
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

3) After taking a Photo and tapping on USE following code get executed

```
 // I use the caputred photo
 [ self  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

After this statement its calling "ViewDidLoad" of MyViewController, which is actually refreshing my screen, I dont want this behaviour.

This problem observed only on iOS 4.2
I am using ARC

Please help me if any one has already faced this issue...

Comment: Are you sure that it is invoking viewDidLoad and not viewDidAppear?

Comment: Does viewDidUnload get called while your modal controller has the screen?

Comment: ViewDidUnload getting called and then Camera is opened. But its not called when we use photo.

Comment: If the view unloads and then you return to that controller, I don't think it has any choice except to call viewDidLoad again.

Comment: After a long work on this found that in iOS 4.2, when camera is opened it consumes lot of memory.  I observed when camera is opened it called low memory warning and called viewDidUnload. After photo taken, USE it call viewDidLoad again. Please reply if any faced this issue..

Comment: I got the solution. The problem is :- In iOS 4.2 when camera opened it  takes huge space. If there is not enough space is available, xib elements are released. Thats why myviewcontroller's viewDidUnload is called. Then after its calling viewDid load etc ……….. Solution:- I fixed this issue by deleting xib elements and crated them from the program. So even if your view controller reloads I can have old details.   Thats all